# Subprocess.wait() in Python 2.7 vz Pthon 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm just migrating my script from Python27 to Python 394 to run my build process like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(_make_clean, creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
p.wait()

p = subprocess.Popen(_make_rebuild, creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
p.wait()
```

Was working pretty nice in Python 27 but now I can see in Python 394 the Python script is not waiting for subprocesses. Of course, here it is necessary to wait until the first one (clean) is finished to start the second one (rebuild). I was able to make it work without the flag 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'. Unfortunately, I need to separate the outputs for users to see what is the progress. It is just a mess if all scripts are running in the same console.

Why it is not working any more?

Comment: Why are you using `Popen` at all here? Try `subprocess.run` instead, as recommended in the `subprocess` documentation.

Comment: Because of many examples for Python27 are using Popen. Even with .run it is not working if the flag 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE' is used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is an interesting finding. I'm using ConEmu as my main terminal and it is fully integrated into Windows. In the past, I was NOT running my scripts over this emulated terminal and that seems to be the reason why I have this issue today. ConEmu is opening a new terminal window for each subprocess but in a different way than the native Windows Command-Line. When the script is called over Windows CMD everything is fine.